# Count rows with max per group and additional condition

Tags: postgresql, group-by, window-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table:

```
 horse_main_id | race_id |    horse_name     | rating100 | race_result 
---------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+-------------
            23 |     159 | Angelology        |       126 |           1
            24 |     159 | Arwoc             |       118 |            
            25 |     159 | Marlo Man         |       118 |            
            26 |     159 | Hucknall          |       113 |            
            27 |     159 | It's Electrifying |       110 |           2
            28 |     159 | Monte Carlo       |       107 |            
            29 |     159 | Cross Constance   |       103 |            
            30 |     160 | Auld Burns        |       119 |            
            31 |     160 | Diamond Jim       |       117 |            
            33 |     160 | Livery            |       115 |            
            34 |     160 | Paraggi           |       115 |            
            35 |     160 | I'll'ava'alf      |       110 |           2
            36 |     160 | Jacks 'n' Kings   |       108 |            
            32 |     160 | Fastnet Isle      |       115 |           1
```

I would like to operate on groups of `race_id`, find all groups that have the `max(rating100)` for their group and `race_result = 1`, and count all the times this happens.

So this example should return only 1, as for race_id 159 group the max rating100 of 126 also has race_result = 1, but for race_id 160 group, the max rating100 is 119, but does not have race_result = 1.

This is the closest I've got (was told I should use window functions):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT horse_name, race_id, race_result
         , max(rating100) OVER (partition by race_id) AS max_rating
    FROM horse_main) t
WHERE race_result = 1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need a subquery in either case, I would use a plain aggregate in the subquery (may be cheaper):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM  (SELECT race_id, max(rating100) AS rating100
       FROM   horse_main
       GROUP  BY 1) x
JOIN   horse_main h USING (race_id, rating100)
WHERE  h.race_result = 1;
```

If there are *many* rows per `race_id`, it will be faster to get group-wise maxima with one of these techniques:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

---

***Or*** use the [window function **`rank()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) - that's what you count effectively: all greatest `rating100` per `race_id` with `race_result = 1`:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM  (SELECT race_result, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY race_id ORDER BY rating100 DESC) AS rnk
       FROM   horse_main) x
WHERE  rnk = 1
AND    race_result = 1;
```

An **index** on `(race_id, rating100 DESC, race_result DESC)` should help performance with big tables.

Assuming `rating100` is defined `NOT NULL`, else you need to add [`NULLS LAST`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492) in query *and* index.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is quite close. In addition to the max *rating100* per group, the derived table should also return the individual *rating100* values, so that you can check if the row's rating matches its group's maximum.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      horse_name,
      race_id,
      race_result,
      rating100,
      max(rating100) OVER (partition by race_id) AS max_rating
    FROM
      horse_main
  ) AS t
WHERE
  race_result = 1
  AND rating100 = max_rating
;
```