# PostgreSQL - maximum of sum over different months with ties over multiple years

Tags: postgresql, cte, greatest-n-per-group

This question is the PostgreSQL version of a question about MySQL 5.6 [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206030/mysql-maximum-of-sum-over-different-months-with-ties-over-multiple-years). Originally, it was one question for both RDBMS's but it was suggested to me that, given the different capabilities of the two systems, I should split the question - in particular I think that CTEs (WITH clause) should make the query far more elegant and readable!

Suppose I have a list of tumours (this data is simulated from real data):

```
CREATE table illness (nature_of_illness VARCHAR(25), created_at DATETIME);

INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Cervix', '2018-01-03 15:45:40');
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Cervix', '2018-01-03 15:45:40');
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Cervix', '2018-01-03 15:45:40');
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Cervix', '2018-01-03 15:45:40');
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Cervix', '2018-01-03 15:45:40');
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Lung',   '2018-01-03 17:50:32');
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Lung',   '2018-02-03 17:50:32');
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Lung',   '2018-02-03 17:50:32');
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Lung',   '2018-02-03 17:50:32');
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Cervix', '2018-02-03 17:50:32');
-- 2017, with 1 Cervix and Lung each for the month of Jan - tie!
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Cervix', '2017-01-03 15:45:40');
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Lung',   '2017-01-03 17:50:32');
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Lung',   '2017-02-03 17:50:32');
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Lung',   '2017-02-03 17:50:32');
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Lung',   '2017-02-03 17:50:32');
INSERT INTO illness VALUES ('Cervix', '2017-02-03 17:50:32');
```

You want to find out which particular tumour was most common in a given month - so far so good!

Now, you will notice that for month 1 of 2017, there is a tie - so it makes **no sense whatsoever** to randomly pick one and give that as the answer - so ties have to be included - this makes the problem much more challenging.

I have a solution but it's quite complex - I'd like to know if my solution is optimal or not. The PostgreSQL fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=cb4b8c376f1c11fe8cc64e44ed2686fe)! The query in the fiddle is very cumbersome - I'll have a look at using CTE's.

My first answer (which works with both PostgreSQL and MySQL) is included in the fiddle but I won't post it here as I believe that it will be superceded by PostgreSQL's superior capabilities and it would be just a copy of my answer to the MySQL question!

Comment: `optimal`? For performance, short code, readability, elegance, portability? What is your first priority? How many rows, and how many distinct kinds of tumour? And is there a table `tumour` with 1 row per existing tumour? And what's your version of Postgres?

Comment: Also, you ask for `a given month`, but query in the fiddle returns all months. Big difference. Which is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### For a *given month*:

```
SELECT tumour_count, illness
FROM (
   SELECT count(*) AS tumour_count, illness
        , rank() OVER (ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   illness
   WHERE  created_at  >= '2017-01-01'  -- given month: 2007-01
   AND    created_at  <  '2017-02-01'  -- optimized for index lookup
   GROUP  BY illness
   ) sub
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

There should be an index on `(created_at)`, or maybe even `(created_at, illness)` to allow index-only scans.

Subqueries are a bit faster than CTEs in Postgres. So only use CTEs where you *need* them, or when performance is not important.

Related:

- [How to optimise window queries in postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74530/how-to-optimise-window-queries-in-postgres/74582#74582)
- [Count rows with max per group and additional condition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139115/count-rows-with-max-per-group-and-additional-condition/139164#139164)

#### For any given period of time

As [requested in the comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206055/postgresql-maximum-of-sum-over-different-months-with-ties-over-multiple-years/206064#comment402320_206064):

```
SELECT to_char(mon, 'YYYY-MM') AS month, tumour_count, illness
FROM  (
   SELECT date_trunc('month', created_at) AS mon
        , illness
        , count(*) AS tumour_count
        , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', created_at)
                       ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   illness
   WHERE  created_at  >= '2017-01-01'  -- period from 2007-01 to 2019-01
   AND    created_at  <  '2019-02-01'
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) sub
WHERE  rnk = 1
ORDER  BY mon, illness;
```

Careful if you have leading or dangling *partial* months, the counts may be misleading.

This is functionally equivalent to what [ypercube already provided](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206058/3684). Just some simplifications to be a bit shorter / faster. And the added filter for a given *period of time*.

Index support becomes less important with the growing share of rows read from the table - and stops being useful at all for more than roughly 5 %. (Exceptions apply, like for index-only scans.)

You can still have ***1 row per month***, by aggregating tying peers. Like:

```
SELECT to_char(mon, 'YYYY-MM') AS month, tumour_count, string_agg(illness, ' | ')
FROM  (
   SELECT date_trunc('month', created_at) AS mon
        , illness
        , count(*) AS tumour_count
        , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', created_at)
                       ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   illness
   WHERE  created_at  >= '2017-01-01'  -- period from 2007-01 to 2019-01
   AND    created_at  <  '2019-02-01'
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) sub
WHERE  rnk = 1
GROUP  BY mon, tumour_count
ORDER  BY mon;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=01f9c4496b29e0f78a52932263ec60aa)*

Comment: Thanks for the input - that indeed does work for the month of January 2017, **but** if I change the later date to 2019, it does a sum of all tumours - 8 of each - I require a count by month with ties also displayed -  over the entire period - the result I want is [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206030/mysql-maximum-of-sum-over-different-months-with-ties-over-multiple-years)

Comment: @Vérace: The short query works for *a given month* (note I added the missing cond. on `rnk`). If you want to query multiple months at once, you need to do more - like @ypercube demonstrated.

Answer (score 4):

Using the window `RANK()` function and `DATE_TRUNC()` (so we don't use `EXTRACT()` twice):

```
  SELECT  
    EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM year_month) AS c_year,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM year_month) AS c_month,
    nature_of_illness,
    month_count
  FROM
    (
      SELECT 
        nature_of_illness,
        DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) AS year_month,
        COUNT(*) AS month_count,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) 
                     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
          AS rnk
      FROM illness
      GROUP BY 
        DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at),
        nature_of_illness
    ) AS t
  WHERE rnk = 1 
  ORDER BY 
    year_month, nature_of_illness ;
```

Test at **[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c0de2331a31ea2cb8300d13adacbc48a)**.

Answer (score 2):

I took a crack at this and had the same general idea that ypercube did. I think his is better but I am submitting this one in case you find it interesting, and because I had fun doing it :)

```
SELECT
    C_YEAR,
    C_MONTH,
    NATURE_OF_ILLNESS,
    MONTH_COUNT
FROM(
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CREATED_AT) C_YEAR,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CREATED_AT) C_MONTH,
    NATURE_OF_ILLNESS,
    COUNT(NATURE_OF_ILLNESS) MONTH_COUNT,
    MAX(COUNT(NATURE_OF_ILLNESS)) OVER (
        PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CREATED_AT),  
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CREATED_AT)) MAX_MONTH_COUNT
FROM 
    ILLNESS
GROUP BY 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CREATED_AT),
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CREATED_AT),
    NATURE_OF_ILLNESS
) AS SICKNESS

WHERE MONTH_COUNT = MAX_MONTH_COUNT
ORDER BY 
    C_YEAR ASC, 
    C_MONTH ASC
```